# Devnagari language support in React Native Expo app

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to create an Expo React Native app with Hindi language support. 
When I paste the actual Hindi text in source code itself within the Text tag, it is rendered as expected. But is it possible to render Hindi texts without actually hardcoding the text itself? Meaning is it possible to type “asdf” and render whatever those characters correspond to a devnagari font of choice?